# Interpolation by holomorphic functions of small exponential type on a half-plane

Tags: cv.complex-variables, interpolation

Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of complex numbers satisfying $|a_n|\le n^2$ and $|a_n|\to \infty$. I'm looking for a function $h(z)$ such that:

(a) $h$ is holomorphic on a half-plane $\{\Re(z) > - \epsilon\}$ for some $\epsilon >0$;

(b) $h(n)=a_n$ for all $n\ge 1$;

(c) $h$ is of exponential type $c<\pi$ on $\{\Re(z) > - \epsilon\}$.

I have tried to construct such an $h$ by using a function $g(z)$ with zeroes of order 1 at each $n$ and letting $$h(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\, a_n \, \frac{g(z)}{g'(n)\, (z-n)}\, e^{\delta(z-n)}$$
for any $\delta>0$. The problem is that I've found only entire functions $g$ with the requested properties and this implies the exponential type of $h$ to be $\ge \pi$. I hope the request that $h$ is holomorphic only on a domain and is not necessarily entire helps.

Comment: Since $h(0)$ is undefined, why the restriction $\Re(z)>-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ instead of $\Re(z)>0$ or $\Re(z)\ge 0$?

Comment: It is enough to consider $\Re(z)\ge 0$. I had in mind a possible strategy to obtain a positive answer that used $\epsilon >0$, but now I know it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is not always possible under your conditions. For example, if $a_n=0$ for  $n\geq 2$, then any function of exponential type $<\pi$ interpolating this sequence must be zero by Carlson's theorem, so if we choose $a_1=1$, interpolation by a function
of this class is impossible.

For Carlson's theorem, see for example, Levin, Distribution of zeros of entire functions, AMS 1970, introduction to Chap IV.

The question has been modified, but the answer is still negative. Suppose that $a_n=P(n), \; n\geq 2$ where $P$ is a polynomial, and $a_1\neq P(1)$.
Then one can apply Carlson's theorem to $f-P$.

Remarks. a) Carlson's theorem applies to functions holomorphic in a half-plane. b) One can generalize the last example, by taking $P$ to be any function of type less than $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now edited the question adding that $|a_n|\to \infty$ which is the case I'm interested in. In any case, I thought that Carlson's Theorem applies to entire functions. Does it hold also for holomorphic functions on a smaller domain?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on Carlson's Theorem.
Given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ with the properties I wrote, are there conditions one can verify to get a positive answer?

Comment: I cannot imagine any interesting sufficient conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.